# Cannot do aggregation on a non aggregation function in AWS Cloudwatch Log Insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Is there a way to do avg(latest(@timestamp) - earliest(@timestamp)) or any alternatives to this query?

Comment: what is earliest is the oldest log?

Comment: Yes it returns the timestamp of the oldest log event. The whole command using is stats avg(latest(@timestamp) - earliest(@timestamp))/1000 by bin(*)